# How to translate the Selenium java methods to ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, selenium-webdriver

I am using ruby with cucumber and selenium-webdriver to test a website. I have been referring to the following list of methods (in java) from the selenium site to write tests. I get an error when trying to use many of the methods listed.

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.DefaultSeleniumMethods.html

Example of my code:

```
text_d = @driver.find_element(:id, "dateDropDown").GetText
```

Error:

```
 undefined method `GetText' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x80d04988> (NoMethodError)
```

I have tried writing GetText as :

Get_Text
get_text
gettext

But still no good. I feel like I'm making a really simple mistake here...

Also methods like .click work fine.

Is  there a separate list of methods that can be used in Ruby? The documentation I've found so far is dominantly Java. This being my first automation project + first time working with Ruby I am having difficulty figuring out what information is useful to what I am doing.

Comment: Did you try this. http://selenium-client.rubyforge.org/

Comment: This is very helpful! It seems these are all methods that are also available for selenium-webdriver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ruby equivalent methods are listed [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/index.html).

On the top right corner click on `Methods`, and search for the `action` you are looking to use.
Keep in mind that you should pick up methods that belong to the class `Selenium::Webdriver`

In your case this is what you need.
[image]

Also there is a mention [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings).

[image]

So long story short, the answer is `text_d = @driver.find_element(:id, "dateDropDown").text`